# Fail to import shap library due to ""numpy.core.multiarray fail to import"

Tags: python, numpy, installation

when i import shap, it shows me the error of numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

and when I ran `shap_values = shap.TreeExplainer(model).shap_values(X)`, it gets the same error.

I tried to uninstall my numpy and reinstall it, to the latest version, does not seems to work

I also tried import numpy.core.multiarray directly, it does not work either

```
import numpy
import numpy.core.multiarray as multiarray
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your numpy version? In some instances you may have more than 1 version of numpy installed and removing extra installations would be good.

```
import numpy
print numpy.__version__
print numpy.__path__
```

and then from there you could delete it using `rm`.

Comment: Yes. I update the numpy for all my environments in the conda. they are all 1.15.4